# Arba'a Vetish'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred ninety-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part two of the Sefer HaMitzvos HaKatzar, covers the 194 prohibitions listed by the Chafetz Chaim that are (Nogea BaZman HaZeh) currently relevant.

Answer (score 1):

According to [*Encyclopaedia Judaica*](http://books.google.com/books?id=LDYOAQAAMAAJ&q=%22one+hundred+and+ninety-four%22), 194 Jews were deported from [Lunéville, France](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lun%C3%A9ville), during the Holocaust.

Answer (score 1):

On the 194th birthday of the Baal Shem Tov (18 Elul 5652), the then Lubavitcher Rebbe, R' Shalom Dovber, heard seven new teachings that the Baal Shem Tov said in Gan Eden, on the initial verses of that week's parshah. These were later publicized and discussed in [one of the public addresses](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16081&pgnum=543) of his son and successor, R' Yosef Yitzchak.

Answer (score 1):

Gematria for צדק! 
צ=90
ד=4
ק=100
90+4+100=194!

Answer (score 0):

*Yishmael* was (dead but) 194 when *Yitzchak* died.